# How can I change Bootstraps screen width breakpoints programatically?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On my web page I have full height 300px sidebar that animates in from the right whenever the user needs to fill out a form.

The problem with this sidebar is that it messes up the grid layout of the main content area, since it's pushing the content instead of just being an overlay.

Programatically I can detect when the sidebar is open. And I would like to change the Bootstrap media query breakpoints whenever it's open.

Is this possible?

Few screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Depending on your structure it should be enough just to change main content area width instead of adding additional @media queries

Comment: You may find that Bootstrap isn't appropriate for this case, it's not a solution for every site.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `flexboxes`, bootstrap isn't designed for that.

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
  const cls = 'is-sidebar-open';
  const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
  
  return wrapper.classList.contains(cls) 
    ? wrapper.classList.remove(cls)
    : wrapper.classList.add(cls)
  ;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  return document
    .querySelector('#toggleSidebar')
    .addEventListener('click', toggleSidebar)
  ;
})
```

```css
.main {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  background: gray;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 0;
  background: cyan;
  transition: 450ms all linear;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.wrapper.is-sidebar-open .sidebar {
  flex-basis: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggleSidebar">Open Sidebar</button>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main"></div>
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```